# Write a $3\times 3$ Matrix as a product of reflective matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to write the Matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 3/5 & 4/5 & 0 \\ 4/5 & -3/5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ as a product of reflections. My thought process was that the products would also be of the form $3\times 3$ and that they would be orthogonal and $\det = -1$. But I don't know where to start and I couldn't find a similar question (my course isn't in English, so I might not use the right keywords). It seems very basic, so if there has been a similar question please link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is a rotation about the origin in the x-y plane, so it should be expressible as the combination of two reflections in lines through the origin.

Suppose we have a 2-D point $(r,\theta)$ and we reflect in a line which makes an angle $\alpha$ to the axis. Then the new point will be $(r,2\alpha - \theta)$.

Reflect again in a line which makes an angle $\beta$ to the axis. Then the new point will be $(r,2\beta-(2\alpha - \theta))$ and we can see we have created a rotation.

Hopefully that is enough to get you going.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that.